# Opening encrypted pdfs in Ubuntu firefox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, pdf, gedit

I am trying to open an encrypted pdf file in the ubuntu version of firefox. I am offered gedit as a default option, which doesn't work - i just get a stream of incomprehensible characters. I usually use Document Viewer. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to decrypt the PDF before you can view it.

Comment: You can choose the application that Firefox opens for particular file types under **Preferences** -> **Applications**. To change the current link you will need to navigate to Document Viewer, which for some unaccountable reason is called `evince`, and is usually in `/usr/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to decrypt it by knowing the password. If it was a encrypted with a public certificate, the Adobe website says that "the user must decrypt the PDF document with the public key that corresponds to the certificate (private key) that was used to encrypt the PDF document". Try opening it in Adobe Reader or Acrobat, and see if it prompts you for a password.